# ReferenceError: MONTH is not defined

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Using the following Google Sheets script:

```
  var currentMonth = MONTH(TODAY);
```

I receive the error `ReferenceError: MONTH is not defined`.

Why is MONTH not defined?

Comment: That's too much of a spreadsheet approach. Try this: `const test = () => console.log(new Date().getMonth())`

Comment: Since you have posted several `ReferenceError` for Google Sheets built-in functions  and Janine's answer give the general answer to all of them I will mark your other questions as duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Janine already mentioned](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153876/88163), `MONTH` and `TODAY` aren't JavaScript functions. In other words,  Google Apps Script use JavaScript as programming language, this language doesn't support Google Sheets functions and some operators that look the same doesn't work the same way. Also it's worthy to mention that Google Sheets and JavaScript doesn't handle dates in exactly the same way, while both handle dates as serial numbers, Google Sheets use one day as unit, while JavaScript uses one milliseconds as unit. Another difference among many more is that each of them has it's own EPOCH (base date ).

On JavaScript,

- `new Date()` is equivalent to Google Sheets `NOW()`.
- `new Date().getMonth() + 1` is equivalent to Google Sheets `=MONTH(TODAY())`.

By the way, Google Apps Script will stop the script execution when an unhandled error occurs, this is why only `MONTH` is reported as a `ReferenceError` and not `TODAY`.

Resources

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Related

- [Is there a way to emulate Vlookup in Google Script?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123670/88163)

Comment: Wonderful Rubén, thank you. I receive the number 5 for `new Date().getMonth() + 1`. Is there a way I can transform this to the name of the month?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date

Answer (score 1):

MONTH and TODAY aren't javascript functions.  You should be using new Date.getMonth().

```
function getCurrentMonth() {
  return new Date().getMonth();
}
```

Comment: You might have to warn the OP that `getMonth()` returns a 0 based index